# Trouble with python Discord bot (discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command None discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I had to remake this bot lately and now it's not working at all. It's a level bot for Discord that auto assigns roles as you level up. I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something with the cogs?

I get this error whenever I run any command:

> [2022-12-26 14:17:35] [ERROR   ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command None
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "rank" is not found

**main.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from private.config import token
import lvlsys

cogs = [lvlsys]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="+", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online!")
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="yo mama"))

async def main():
    for i in range(len(cogs)):
        await cogs[i].setup(client)

client.run(token)
```

**lvlsys.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from pymongo import MongoClient
from discord.utils import get

# Channels
...
# Levels
...
# Database
...
# Commands

class lvlsys(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
       self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
...

    @commands.command()
    async def rank(self, ctx):
...

    @commands.command()
    async def leaderboard(self, ctx):
...

    @commands.command()
    async def givexp(self, userID: int, addedxp: int, ctx):
...
                           

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(lvlsys(client))
```

I've played around with the cogs but ultimately, nothing has worked.

**Edit:**
Importing asyncio, using setup_hook() and load_extension() in main.py, actually executing the main function and making sure client.run(token) is below the main function fixed the issue.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="+", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"Online.")

async def setup_hook():
  await client.load_extension("Cogs.lvlsys")
  
async def main():
  await setup_hook()
  
asyncio.run(main())
client.run(os.environ['token'])
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load the Cogs in `main`, but you're never actually *calling* that `main` function, so you're never loading your extensions, so the Cog is never attached. Python doesn't know that it first has to run your asynchronous `main` function before running the rest of the code...

`setup_hook` is the recommended place to do this sort of stuff in. If you don't want to use it for whatever reason, you'll have to start the bot using `start` instead of `run` instead, and start your `main` manually. See the link below for both (but just use `setup_hook`, it makes your life easier).

This is also not the greatest:

```py
    for i in range(len(cogs)):
        await cogs[i].setup(client)
```

[`load_extension`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension) was invented for this very purpose. Don't loop over a list of imports and manually call the `setup` method.

There's a few examples on how to load cogs, one of them can be found in the migration guide: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

This explains how to use `setup_hook` as well as manual async mains (but, again, just use `setup_hook`).

**Also** don't call `change_presence` in `on_ready`, it can make Discord disconnect you. There's really 0 reason to do it because you can just pass your presence info when you create the `commands.Bot` instance directly.

*PS. if you're looping over a list of items, just do `for item in collection` instead of indexing over `range(len(collection))`*